# "RuntimeError: No surface found at the given iso value" Error while converting 3d numpy array to mesh

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-image

The program is to segment a given CT scan. I have created a deep learning model to do that. I read the CT scan as a .nrrd file in python converting it to numpy array and then trained my model on this. Than using this model I predicted a numpy array which is working right. The issue occurs when I try to convert this 3d numpy array in to a mesh and eventually in .stl format.

```
predImg = predictVolume(imgTarget)
vertices,faces,_,_ = marching_cubes_lewiner(predImg)

def dataToMesh(vert, faces):
mm = mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(faces.shape[0], dtype=mesh.Mesh.dtype))
for i, f in enumerate(faces):
    for j in range(3):
        mm.vectors[i][j] = vert[f[j],:]
return mm


mm = dataToMesh(vertices, faces)
mm.save('tooth-segmented.stl')
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well. It took me a little while to figure it out, but it has to do with the "level" parameter from scikit-image's marching cube algorithm (I am assuming that is the package you are using and not another one).

The "iso value" in question is the "isolevel" value which is the level parameter for the function. If you don't provide anything the function will pick the mean voxel value of your image array. For example, if you supplied a mask of 0s and 1s the default value would be 0.5. The marching cubes algorithm would then create a surface that separates voxels above and below 0.5 from each other.

In my experience I encountered this error when I mistakenly ran the marching cubes algorithm for an array of zeros. Because all the voxels were zero, the level was also zero, and the algorithm couldn't actually draw a surface.

I would recommend checking what your data-array input looks like and what your expected default level parameter would be. If it turns out your issue was like mine then you'll need to adjust the input array somehow. Otherwise, you can adjust your level value to something suitable for your data (eg. if you wanted to segment bone in a CT image you'd probably want to pick a HU value around 1000 for your level.